# Is it possible to use two different entities when constructing a SQL query in C#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to incorporate another database into my code, but I am unable to do so. Is there a proper way to use two entities for one query?

```
List<AlertsReportResult> resultList = new List<AlertsReportResult>();

using (var dbContext = new TestHHCEntities())
{
    var alert = from alertEvents in dbContext.Test_AlertEvents
                where alertEvents.IsAlert
                group alertEvents by alertEvents.MemberIssuesID into g
                select g.OrderBy(p => p.AlertDate).FirstOrDefault();

    using (var dbSecondContext = new Test2_14Entities())
    {
```

Whenever I do this, I don't get back any data.

Comment: Then the query/expectations are likely wrong. While a Queryable cannot span contexts, one can use values from a completed query later on - including another context source. These values have the same restrictions as any used (ie. if found in an array declared in code).

Comment: Please provide us with a [mcve]. From your code, it's unclear what your question is all about.

Comment: This is usually the kind of thing you should be doing on the DBMS side, not the progreamm side. A stored function should be able to do this. Otherwise you may have to use 2 queries in sequence - one per database.

Comment: I was thinking it would be best to utilize a raw SQL/stored procedure string, but the previous programmer wrote this up in C# and I need to make edits without changing the entire report.

Comment: @dymanoid I am only curious about what is the proper way to utilize two different entities within one file.

Comment: You can't perform operations on 2 contexts as others have stated. What you CAN do is fetch some data from context 1 into a list or other object and then use that with context 2 such as  `context1List.Contains(c2.Field)` Don't nest your `using` - do them sequentially.  Need more info on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

fetch the result outside of the `using` context

```
var resultOfFirstDbContext = //new FirstDto(); initialize the object of the first query

var resultOfTheSecondDbContext = //new SecondDto(); new List<SecondDto>(); initialize the object of the second query

using (var dbContext = new TestHHCEntities())
{
    resultOfFirstDbContext = (from alertEvents in dbContext.Test_AlertEvents
                where alertEvents.IsAlert
                group alertEvents by alertEvents.MemberIssuesID into g)
                .OrderBy(p => p.AlertDate)
                .Select(x => new FirstDto
                             {
                                 Property1 = x.Property1, .....
                             }).FirstOrDefault();
}

using (var secondDbContext = new Test2_14Entities())
{
      resultOfTheSecondDbContext = secondDbContext.Entities
                                   .Where(second => 
                                       second.Property1 == resultOfFirstDbContext.Property1 
                                       && ....)
                                 //.ToList(); or .FirstOrDefault();
}

//you can now use `resultOfTheSecondDbContext` here
```